# pandas matching on level of hierarchical index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to make a summary DataFrame but they way it is filled in is causing problems because no check is made on the labels.

Here is a toy example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arrays = [np.hstack([ ['one']*3, ['two']*3]), ['Dog', 'Bird', 'Cat']*2]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['foo', 'bar'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((3,6)),columns=columns,
                  index=pd.date_range('20000103',periods=3))

df['one'] = pd.DataFrame({'Bird' : np.ones(3)*2,
                          'Dog' : np.ones(3),
                          'Cat' : np.ones(3)*3},
                          index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=3))
df['two'] = pd.DataFrame({'Dog' : np.ones(3)*4,
                          'Bird' : np.ones(3)*5,
                          'Cat' : np.ones(3)*6,},
                          index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=3))
```

The output is:

```
foo            one          two
bar        Dog Bird Cat Dog Bird Cat
2000-01-03 2   3    1   5   6    4
2000-01-04 2   3    1   5   6    4
2000-01-05 2   3    1   5   6    4
```

Where I would expect:

```
foo            one          two
bar        Dog Bird Cat Dog Bird Cat
2000-01-03 1   2    3   4   5    6
2000-01-04 1   2    3   4   5    6
2000-01-05 1   2    3   4   5    6
```

The issue is that the frame is sorted alphabetically by column. It is then inserted into the larger frame with the values sorted and the column label is then wrong.

So my question is if there is a way to make sure that the column labels are matched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to re-order the columns of your temporary dataframe as it's being assigned, using the column order from the larger dataframe.

```
In [50]: df['one'] = pd.DataFrame({'Bird' : np.ones(3)*2,
                                   'Dog' : np.ones(3),
                                   'Cat' : np.ones(3)*3},
                                   index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=3))
                                   [df['one'].columns]

In [51]: df['two'] = pd.DataFrame({'Dog' : np.ones(3)*4,
                                   'Bird' : np.ones(3)*5,
                                   'Cat' : np.ones(3)*6,},
                                   index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=3))
                                   [df['two'].columns]

In [52]: df
Out[52]: 
foo         one             two           
bar         Dog  Bird  Cat  Dog  Bird  Cat
2000-01-03    1     2    3    4     5    6
2000-01-04    1     2    3    4     5    6
2000-01-05    1     2    3    4     5    6
```

Answer (score 2):

This should align on the levels (though their is some ambiguity *how* to do it, e.g. on which level). https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7655

You should do this instead:

```
In [10]: one = pd.DataFrame({'Bird' : np.ones(3)*2,
                             'Dog' : np.ones(3),
                             'Cat' : np.ones(3)*3},
                             index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=3))

In [11]: two = pd.DataFrame({'Dog' : np.ones(3)*4,
   ....:                     'Bird' : np.ones(3)*5,
   ....:                     'Cat' : np.ones(3)*6,},
   ....:                     index= pd.date_range('20000103',periods=3))

In [12]: one
Out[12]: 
            Bird  Cat  Dog
2000-01-03     2    3    1
2000-01-04     2    3    1
2000-01-05     2    3    1

In [13]: two
Out[13]: 
            Bird  Cat  Dog
2000-01-03     5    6    4
2000-01-04     5    6    4
2000-01-05     5    6    4

In [14]: concat([one,two],keys=['one','two'],axis=1)
Out[14]: 
             one             two          
            Bird  Cat  Dog  Bird  Cat  Dog
2000-01-03     2    3    1     5    6    4
2000-01-04     2    3    1     5    6    4
2000-01-05     2    3    1     5    6    4
```

Comment: I ended up just adding columns=df['one'] as suggested below. I had thought that this would be done automatically. Perhaps enforcing this assignment is the best way to fix this. At least that would throw an error if they did not match.